# How to get all table id's from bigquery without partitioning?

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I'm using node.js bigquery client library and need to get a list of tables from а dataset without partitioning block.

For example, I have a number of partitioned tables:

- table1_20170101
- table1_20170102
- ...
- table1_20170131
- table2_20170101
- table2_20170102
- ...
- table2_20170131

I need to get **[table1,table2]** as a result but using **getTables** method I get **[table1_20170101,table1_20170102...]**

Script example below:

```
dataset.getTables(function (err, tables) {
    let result = [];

    for (let key in tables) {
        result.push(tables[key].id);
    }
    console.log(result);
    res.send(result);
});
```

Is there any available method to get "unpartitioned" table names?

Getting all tables with **_date**, split and make it unique seems to be very slow if there're a lot of partitioned tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perform a query against the `__TABLES_SUMMARY__` table, instead of using the `getTables` method.

The sample below gets all the tables in a Dataset, splits the name on the `_` character and takes the first part. It then creates a distinct list.

```
bigquery.query({
  query: [
    'SELECT DISTINCT SPLIT(table_id,"_")[ORDINAL(1)] as tableName',
    'FROM `DATASETNAME.__TABLES_SUMMARY__`;'
  ].join(' '),

  params: []
}, function(err, rows) {
  let result = [];

  for (row of rows) {
    result.push(row.tableName);
  }
  console.log(result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a meta query:

```
select * from  `wr_live.__TABLES_SUMMARY__`
```